# Autoclick search button (android)

Tags: android, listview, search, click

Okay,I've been following this tutorial http://coenraets.org/blog/android-samples/androidtutorial/
Basically it gives me exactly what i need for my app

ONLY , I need the search button (or query) to be autoclicked...

I want the user to open the app and see the list already queried

also I have integrated this tutorial into a Tab application, so keep that in mind...

Please any help would be amazing!!! thank you a lot for taking time out of your lives to help me with this stupid thing

I'm a complete noob , I'm learning as I go

Thanka a lot again!

Fadi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best way to achieve 'autoclicking' would be through the textwatcher-interface:

> http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html

Like this:

```
EditText.addTextChangedListener(...)

afterTextChanged(Editable s)
{
//Make your query here using s.getText().toString
//as your WHERE-Clause
}
```

I would advise you, to debug while using the TextWatcher just to understand how it works ;)
You should also consider that this method could use up a lot of memory, since you query your database with every letter that is typed. You could count the letters typed though, in

```
onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
```

and setting a boolean value to true, when the user has typed more then 2 letters and start querying your DB then to avoid too much memory usage.

Edit:

This is the original search-Method:

```
public void search(View view) {
        // || is the concatenation operation in SQLite
                cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT _id, firstName, lastName, title FROM employee WHERE firstName || ' ' || lastName LIKE ?", 
                                                new String[]{"%" + searchText.getText().toString() + "%"});
                adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                                this, 
                                R.layout.employee_list_item, 
                                cursor, 
                                new String[] {"firstName", "lastName", "title"}, 
                                new int[] {R.id.firstName, R.id.lastName, R.id.title});
                employeeList.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

Now try it like this:

```
searchText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

@Override
public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
}
@Override
public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
} 
@Override
afterTextChanged(Editable s){
            // || is the concatenation operation in SQLite
                    cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT _id, firstName, lastName, title FROM employee WHERE firstName || ' ' || lastName LIKE ?", 
                                                    new String[]{"%" + s.getText().toString() + "%"});
                    adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                                    this, 
                                    R.layout.employee_list_item, 
                                    cursor, 
                                    new String[] {"firstName", "lastName", "title"}, 
                                    new int[] {R.id.firstName, R.id.lastName, R.id.title});
                    employeeList.setAdapter(adapter);
      }
});
```

There are some blanks in the code which you have to fill in by yourself. But that's the basic idea behind my first post.

Comment: umm thanks alot for this , but where do i put this?, do i make a new activity?

Comment: okay, I did it! , now it works but ... I can't use the search button anymore , every time i click the search button the app fails

Comment: okay, so i managed to make it work, now when you open the app , i get the list ready , Perfect! only problem is that now the search button doesn't work... :(

Comment: what about the search button :(

Comment: I Fixed it!!!! okay i just added the public void search(View view) {
        // || is the concatenation operation i...etc etc
thanks alot! your answer thou is what made it possible!!!

Answer (score 0):

Look here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextWatcher.html

Try this:

```
EditText searchTo = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.medittext);
searchTo.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    }
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
    }
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        // autoclicked here!
    } 
});
```

Comment: Hey, Thanks a lot for this ... now where do i put this :$

Comment: I managed to figure out where to put it , but now , the search button doesn't work , every time i click it to search somthing the app crashes ! but the list is there , so the button has been autoclicked i guess!! thanks alot , do you have an idea why its crashing thou?

Comment: this one worked without adding anything to it , with the later activities